# Go http + goroutines

Tags: golang, http

Здравствуйте. Я понимаю как использовать goroutines, но мне интересно: можно ли их использовать, при написании веб сайта (пользуясь библиотекой net/http). 
И еще: в каких случаях следует использовать веб сокеты, а в каких - net/http?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если Вы внимательно посмотрите в исходники упомянутой Вами net/http, то увидите там что каждый запрос порождает отдельную goroutine